# HTMLBody of e-mail loses its format when meeting text attached

Tags: vba, outlook

I created VBA code that will attach something at the end of every e-mail.

```vb
With objItem
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<p><p>" & TextID
End With
```

It usually works, but when I generate an e-mail from a meeting (the meeting minutes/summary) it loses its format. I did a test & even a direct `.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody` won't keep the format.

Original e-mail:
[image]

After I apply code.
[image]

My guess is appointment and meeting objects don't have the `.HTMLBody` property.

1. Is my guess accurate?
2. Is there a workaround that doesn't require a copy-paste from an e-mail or the inspector?
3. Is there a way to detect that the e-mail comes from a meeting?

Comment: Why are you using `<p>`? I think that's the cause. What happens if you use `<br>` instead?

Comment: Also, the right way to use the `<p>` tag is to use it as a container, like a `<div>` - So something like this `<p>This is inside the paragraph</p> but this is not`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I detected that, when I generate an e-mail from a meeting (the meeting minutes/summary) it basically loses its format

Appointments (meetings) don't use the HTML based message bodies. Instead, the [RTFBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.rtfbody) property is available for them. You can use the `StrConv` function in Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) or Visual Basic to convert an array of bytes to a string.

You can use a low-level on which Outlook is built - Extended MAPI. The PR_HTML property (DASL is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10130102`) returns the HTML markup unlike the OOM.

But there is a universal solution - use the Word object model for dealing wit message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.